# Which SQL Query Should I Use in this Situation

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, t-sql

I have a table `tbl_comments` in MySQL. There are four fields `user_name`, `comment_id`, `user_likes`, `user_dislikes` in the table. The `user_likes` and `user_dislikes` fields are of type VARCHAR and there are comma separated user_names in these two fields.

I have the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comments WHERE comment_id=223";
```

My problem is I also want to pass the user_name with this query and get the following output

```
1.  0 (if user_name does not exist in user_likes and user_dislikes)
2.  1 (if user_name exists in user_likes)
3.  2 (if user_name exists in user_dislikes)
```

Which SQL query can give my desired results?

Comment: I think you'll run into trouble with your application if you have lists of foreign keys in CSV format inside a single column. I'd recommend changing your design so that you have a new table, `user_opinion`, which connects `from_user_id`, `to_user_id`, `type` (where the type is either L or D).

Comment: Actually I am developing a forum. And Your suggestion looks valuable. I think I should Redesign my database. Can You please refer me any good article, tutorial etc which can Help me in this Regard. As I want my Application More Efficient.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a tutorial that will help you with this _specific_ problem, but if you learn about database normalisation, as Andre suggests, that will certainly help. On another note: it's fine to develop a forum for learning purposes, but bear in mind there are a number of mature and well-testd PHP forum packages out there already!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are using SQL Server:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
WHEN (if user_name does not exist in user_likes and user_dislikes) THEN O
WHEN (if user_name exists in user_likes) THEN 1
WHEN (if user_name exists in user_dislikes) THEN 2
END
FROM tbl_comments WHERE comment_id=223
```

This is roughly what you need. Please change the conditions inside **WHEN** as per your use.
But I don't understand what 'user_likes' and 'user dislikes' actually take, and why comma-separated user names? So the conditions are left unchanged.

Comment: The user is using MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks but how to access this value, I mean there is no field name specified with this.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the pitfall of using comma-separated values before myself. Here's a good answer on the subject: [Is storing a delimited list in a database colum really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

You would have to use LIKE '%user_name%' and that's not good from a efficiency point-of-view. Try looking into database normalization.

(My first post on Stackoverflow :))

Comment: Thanks For Your Suggestion. Actually, I was ignoring this fact. But When I read your given article and the references in it, It helped me a lot. Thanks for this precious suggestion. I do not want to compromise efficiency.